# Does "Encrypt Phone" work on Android 5.0 Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created android 5.0 emulator using Android SDK (google api intel x86 atom_64 image).  Power on the emulator, go to settings/security, click "Encrypt Phone", it just reboot the emulator, no encryption ever happen.

But I was able to encrypt 4.4 Emulator, so I am wondering if "Encrypt Phone" still works on 5.0 + Emulator. If not, how to use the new "Android For Work" API on emulator?

Thanks.